# How do I color Devanagiri diacritics in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I have a project in ReactJS. I wish the diacritic of a Devanagiri letter to have a different color than the letter that it attached to.

For eg: क + ी make की

Is there a way to make the क to have a different color than the ी in the combined letter की?

I have tried the following:

```
क<span style="color: blue;">ी</span>
```

It works fine when it's only the individual letters, but it has one uniform color when it's combined.

Comment: [Here's a hack](https://tsplay.dev/mb0qow) using `position: absolute` which overlays the non-diacritic version on the diacritic version. It's a terrible idea for accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use this syntax ?

```
क<span style={{color: 'blue'}}>ी</span>
```

Comment: Yes, that did not work.

Comment: got it, I simply add &nbsp; at beginning and the end of character and it worked, take a look at this on : <span style={{ color: "blue" }}>&nbsp;ीकक&nbsp;</span>

Comment: I don't understand why is not working without &nbsp, but it probably doesn't recognize the diacritic of a Devanagiri as a character